# How to compare form, model and auth_User in Django

Tags: django, forms

I have a idea to create something like a admin panel. In that panel the user (or admin as well) for example in my case will can add a field named "website". And in this moment I have a problem. I've create in myapp model Website:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Website(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="website_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.CharField(help_text="Podaj stronę wraz z http lub https",max_length=250,verbose_name='Strona www', unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.website
```

after that I've create a form to display for the user when is loggin:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Website

class WebsiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = ('website',)
```

Next step was a creating view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import LoginForm, UserRegistrationForm, WebsiteForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Website
...
@login_required
def add_website(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        website_form = WebsiteForm(data=request.POST)
        if website_form.is_valid():
            new_website = website_form.save(commit=False)
            new_website.post = add_website
            new_website.save()
    else:
        website_form = WebsiteForm()
    return render(request, 'konto/add_website.html', {'add_website': add_website, 'website_form': website_form})
```

and on the end I've create a html file responsible for displaying form and action

```
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if new_website %}
        <h2>Twója strona oczekuje na zaakceptowanie</h2>
        {% else %}
        <h4>Dodaj stronę do monitorowania</h4>
        <form action="." method="POST">
        {{website_form.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Dodaj stronę"></p>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
        <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Powrót</a>
        {% endif %}
```

My problem is that, when I'am login as for example admin, I trying to add new record using this form. But the nothing is happen. I fill the form, and after click button the script redirecting me to the dashboard. In dashboard I have a blank list of added websites. 
part of code in dashboard.html

```
...
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
Twoja www:
{% for website in websites %}
{{website.website}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
...
```

and the view for displaying list of websites:

```
@login_required
def website(request):
    websites = Website.objects.all().order_by('-User')
    context = {'websites:', websites}
    return render(request, 'konto/dashboard.html', context=context)
```

I want to make a list of pages, so that the user who added the page, only saw his records and not all that exist in the database.
EDIT:
And sometimes when I change form link I have a error

```
IntegrityError at /konto/add-website/
NOT NULL constraint failed: konto_website.user_id
```

EDIT:

Now I have something like this:

```
@login_required
def new_website(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_website = WebsiteForm(request.POST)
        if new_website.is_valid():
            new_website=new_website.save(commit=False)
            new_website.user = request.user
            new_website.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Pomyślnie dodano stronę')
            return render(request, 'konto/add_website_ok.html')
    else:
        new_website = WebsiteForm()
    return render(request, 'konto/add_website.html', {'new_website':new_website})
```

Everything is working ok, if I'am login as admin, I can add new website as a admin. If I login for example as a user, I can add new website as a user. In Django Admin I can see every record whos was added by users. But I've create also something like dashboard in my own control panel. And in that control panel I want to display the list of websites added by users. For example, if I'am login as 'user' i can see only my webpages, not all from the list.
I want to display it in dashboard.html as:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<b>Monitoring www:</b>
{% for website in website_list %}
{{website.website}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But now I see only a label 'Monitoring www', nothing else..
I think You understand me. :)

2nd EDIT

view
@login_required

```
def website(request):
    website_list = Website.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-User')
    context = {'website_list:', website_list}
    return render(request, 'konto/dashboard.html', context=context)
```

html

```
{% for website in website_list %}
{{website.website}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing here

```
    if website_form.is_valid():
        new_website = website_form.save(commit=False)
        new_website.post = add_website
        new_website.save()
```

But I think it should work if it is simplified to:

```
    if website_form.is_valid():
        new_website = website_form.save()


@login_required
def add_website(request):
    variables = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        website_form = WebsiteForm(data=request.POST)
        if website_form.is_valid():
            new_website = website_form.save(commit=False)
            new_website.post = add_website
            new_website.save()
    else:
        website_form = WebsiteForm()

    variables['add_website'] = add_website
    variables['website_form'] = website_form
    if new_website: variables['new_website'] = True

    return render(request, 'konto/add_website.html', variables)
```

Comment: Henry I solve this problem with adding new records. But I have another. 
How to display records added by a given user. In order for the user to see only his records after logging in, not all of them that exist in the database?

Comment: Can't you simply filter the queryset on the user?

Comment: I wrote the code in my question look at->  "def websites..."

Comment: `websites = Website.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: Ok I made it, but in html file still I have nothing :( I have only the label : Twoje strony www - but the list of websites is not displaying

Comment: You do not pass new_website to your context so it doesn't get to the template

Comment: Henry can You write me how I can write it? I think I don't understand

Comment: something like the above

Comment: Henry look at my question I updated it by edit. That's why I asked You a command of filter:)

Comment: But you are not passing `website_list` through so the list is empty which is why it displays nothing

Comment: If You understand me, can You help me ? What I need to write to have a list of records in dashboard?

Comment: Look at your code.  In the EDIT section you are passing `"websites":websites` but in the template you are using `website_list`